# Get IIS Application Name in .NET App

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I am currently using the following code:

```
<center>Application Name: <%=HostingEnvironment.ApplicationID %></center>
```

Which outputs:

```
Application Name: /LM/W3SVC/1/Root/AppName
```

"AppName" is the value I want and I'm wondering whether there is another method that will simply return it without having to do string magic to remove the rest of the path.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

To reiterate, based on the comment thread - **`ApplicationHost.GetSiteName()` is not intended to be used in code** (see [msdn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.iapplicationhost.getsitename(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> ### IApplicationHost.GetSiteName Method ()
>
> This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be
>   used directly from your code.

Instead use

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.SiteName;
```

[Documentation at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.sitename(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

you can use this routine to get fully qualified application path, context.Request.ApplicationPath will contain application name

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Return full path of the IIS application
    /// </summary>
    public string FullyQualifiedApplicationPath
    {
        get
        {
            //Getting the current context of HTTP request
            var context = HttpContext.Current;

            //Checking the current context content
            if (context == null) return null;

            //Formatting the fully qualified website url/name
            var appPath = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}",
                                        context.Request.Url.Scheme,
                                        context.Request.Url.Host,
                                        context.Request.Url.Port == 80
                                            ? string.Empty
                                            : ":" + context.Request.Url.Port,
                                        context.Request.ApplicationPath);

            if (!appPath.EndsWith("/"))
                appPath += "/";

            return appPath;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of these should do the job depending on what your IIS app/site structure is

```
HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName()

HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath

new ServerManager().Sites;  //This is a List so you can iterate and match with a eliminating hint
```

Comment: `ApplicationHost.GetSiteName()` is not intended to be used in code (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.iapplicationhost.getsitename(v=vs.110).aspx). Instead use `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.SiteName;`.

Comment: @EvilDr can you please send this as an answer? I would like to upvote it.